# Where does the term "shiv" (a makeshift dagger) actually come from?

Tags: etymology

Practically everyone has read (or seen in a film or on TV) about a situation in which someone "stuck a shiv" into someone else. The image is of some kind of dagger, and the most common use I have observed for *shiv* is as a term for the kind of makeshift dagger used by prison inmates.

I use the term *dagger* because the *shiv* in this case appears to be a thrusting weapon, not a slashing one. Yet its etymology is not really clear. Etymonline describes it this way:

> "a razor," 1915, variant of *chive*, thieves' cant word for "knife" (1670s), of unknown origin.

The American Heritage Dictionary weights in with:

> A knife, razor, or other sharp or pointed implement, especially one used as a weapon. [Probably Romani *chiv*, blade.]

Several other sources plump for the Romani explanation, dating from the early 20th century, but while Collins says the term's origin in British English is the Romani one, it insists that the American term is from 1855-60, although on the subject of actual origin it is strangely mute. This makes me suspect it also favors the Romani origin—but how?

All this seems something of a muddle. Certainly the usages may have sprung up independently, but then there's that "of unknown origin" given by Etymonline, dating it from the 17th century. Can anyone provide a clearer picture?

**Side note:** I wonder if there could be some kind of line traceable between this term and one meaning of *shiver*, about which Etymonline says:

> "small piece, splinter, fragment, chip," c. 1200, perhaps from an unrecorded Old English word, related to Middle Low German *schever schiver* "splinter," Old High German *scivero*, from Proto-Germanic *skif- "split" (source also of Old High German *skivaro* "splinter," German *Schiefer* "splinter, slate"), from PIE root *skei- "to cut, split." Commonly in phrases to break to shivers "break into bits" (mid-15c.). Also, shiver is still dialectal for "a splinter" in Norfolk and Lincolnshire.

When I entertain this term in my mind's eye I see a sharp shard of glass or ceramic that could look very much like a dagger.

Comment: I don’t like to entertain the thought of a shiv in anyone’s eye. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Shiv* (preferred spelling in US slang) is from **chiv** or **chive** in thieves' cant (from British slang). *Chiv* is from **chivomengro** (meaning *knife* in Gypsy or Romani language) according to several sources. Most cant terms are said to be from Anglo-Romani language which has roots in Sanskrit. The word might be related to the Gypsy word *churi* (meaning *knife*) and ultimately Sanskrit word [छुरी (churī)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%9B%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80) (meaning *knife, dagger*).

*OED* mentions that *chiv(e)* (n) is from thieve's cant and has the earliest usage from 1673:

> R. Head *Canting Acad.* 12       He takes his Chive and cuts us down.

Listed below are the sources mentioning *chivomengro*:

From *[Modern Language Notes](https://books.google.ca/books?id=oxQ5AAAAMAAJ&q=%22this%20word%20first%20noted%20in%201673%22&dq=%22this%20word%20first%20noted%20in%201673%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwici7m-m6_nAhUGH80KHaujBFkQ6AEIKTAA)* (by Johns Hopkins Press):

> Another cant term which may have come from the Romani is 
>   *chive* 'knife'. This word first noted in 1673 (N.E.D.) is still in 
>   use at the present time. The preferred spelling is *chive* , but it is 
>   often given as *chivvy , chiv, shiv* , or *shive*. The pronunciation is 
>   either 'shiv' (rhyming with 'to live') or 'shivvy'. There is a 
>   Gypsy word *chivomengro* 'knife' whose stem 'chiv' suggests 
>   itself as the origin of the underworld *chive*.

From *Wise Young Fool* (by Sean Beaudoin):

> A shiv (from the Romani word *chivomengro*, or "knife") is a slang term for any sharp or pointed implement used as a weapon. Inmates in prisons around the world make shivs.

From *[Journal of the Gypsy Lore Society](https://books.google.ca/books?id=FImgAAAAMAAJ&q=%22chivo%20mingra%22%20%22chivomengro%22&dq=%22chivo%20mingra%22%20%22chivomengro%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiykr2Hna_nAhXOZc0KHRUMDnMQ6AEIKTAA)* (by The Society):

[image]

---

Some sources say that it is from *Gypsy* *chive* meaning 'to stab':

From "A Dictionary of Slang, Jargon & Cant: Embracing English, American, and Anglo-Indian Slang, Pidgin English, Tinker's Jargon and Other Irregular Phraseology" by Albert Barrère, Charles Godfrey Leland:

[image]

From "A Classical Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue" by Francis Grose:

[image]

Comment: In Scottish English, the noun/verb is "chib". Dictionary of the Scots Language.=. https://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/sndns789

Answer (score 4):

*Shiv* is of Romany origin.  It is included by George Borrow in his *Romano Lavo-Lil Word-Book of the Romany or English Gypsy Language* (1874):

> - **chiv**, **chiva**, **chuva**: *verbum activum* to cast, fling, throw, place, put.

Eric Partridge in his *Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English* (3rd edition, 1949) has the following about *chive* or *chiv* which are variants of *shiv*:

> - ***chive*** or ***chiv*** - of Romany origin - 17th-20th century cant for a knife, a file, a saw; Romany and cant for to stab, to cut or saw (through), to ‘knife’: mid 18th-20th century (Grose, 1st edition)

Grose refers to *A Classical Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue* first published in 1785 where *chive* or *chife* is defined as *a knife, file or saw*.  Partridge edited Grose's dictionary and added comments to it.  Here is Partridge's addition to *chive*:

> - In Romany *chive* has the specific sense to stab, from *chiv*, *chiva* (*chive*), *chuva*, to cast, fling, throw, also to place, put.  G.B.

G.B. stands here for George Borrow and brings us back to the *Romano Lavo-Lil*.

Yet more information is found in Partridge's *Dictionary of the Underworld British & American* (1949):

> - ***Shiv***, noun, is a variant of *shive*, than which, indeed, it is much more common.  In e.g. Ersine [Noel Ersine, *Underworld and Prison Slang*, 1933]
> - ***Shive*** A knife, late 19th-20th century.  Donald Lowrie, who was at San Quentin in 1901-11, makes an old hand say, in reference to the 1890's, ‘I always carried a shive m'self.  Everybody carried a shive.  Y'r had t' carry one.’ (*My life in Prison*, 1912)

It is interesting to note that in numerous languages one of the slang words for knife has also been borrowed from Romany but directly from *ćhuri* meaning knife in that language.  It appears for example in French as *chourin*, which is now obsolete, or *surin*, which is still used.  Wartburg in his *Französisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch* has the following remark about it:

> - *chourin* ist aus dem zigeunerischen *churí* entlehnt, so auch im argot von Barcelona *xurí*, im calo Spaniens *churí*.
> - *chourin* is borrowed from Romany, as in Barcelona slang *xurí* and in Spanish caló *churí*.

Answer (score 2):

Green's Dictionary of Slang appears to support the Romani origin with the earliest usage of *chiv* from the second half of the 17th century and *shiv* from the late 19th century:

> ### [chiv](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/kqeadvi) *n.<sup>1</sup>*
>
> *also* **chev**, **chevy**, **chib**, **chieve**, **chiff**, **chive**, **chivie**, **chivvy**, **chivy**, **skiv**
>
> [Rom. *chiv*, *chive*, a knife]
>
> 1. (*UK Und.*) a knife or razor.
>
>    - 1674    [UK]    ‘Of the Budge’ HEAD *Canting Academy* (1674) 12: For when he hath nubbed us, / And our friends tips him no cole, / He takes his Chive and cuts us down / And tips us into the hole.
>
> ### [shiv](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/tnbdmki) *n.*
>
> *also* **schieve**, **sheive**, **shieve**, **shive**, **shivy**
>
> [CHIV n.<sup>1</sup>]
>
> - 1897    [US]    J. LONDON ‘The Road’ in HENDRICKS & SHEPHERD *Jack London Reports* (1970) 311–21: Their argot is peculiar study. [...] shiv, knife.

The Concise New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English suggests a different origin of [shiv](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=Ak6cBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1482&lpg=PA1482&dq=boof%20meaning%20slang&source=bl&ots=a5P_4j4q2M&sig=Au9QBXr6hzwQ5rEdw2GQhlvQaV0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjs_ePht97dAhVP1BoKHYYmB9s4ChDoATAFegQIAxAB#v=onepage&q=shiv&f=false):

> Probably from “*shive*” (to slice bread), 1570.